# Use @angular/core module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I would like to use the DI of the angular 2 core module in my server code. What is the best way to use the @angular/core module on my node.js server?

My first attempt was to compile my typescript code to ES5 and import the core module directly which is not working, because some of the core code is written in ES6.

My second attempt was to bundle everything with webpack, but then "Reflect" is somehow missing. I tried polyfills but without luck so far.

Anyone an other idea?